# Specify background color when rotating an image using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to rotate an image in Python using OpenCV with the following code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]

img_center = (cols / 2, rows / 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(img_center, 45, 1)

rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows))
```

The code works as it should, but the background where the image is no longer visible turns black. I want the background to be white and I'm therefore wondering if it's possible to specify the color `OpenCV` should use for it when rotating.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510225/rotating-image-in-python-extrapolate-background-color) but for `PIL`.

Comment: **Read the documentation** for warpAffine at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983. See borderMode and borderValue arguments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [warpAffine](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine) parameter `borderMode` can be used to control how the background will be handled.  You can set this to `cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT` to make the background a solid color, then choose the color with the parameter `borderValue`.  For example, if you want a green background, use

```
rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows),
                           borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                           borderValue=(0,255,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill the borders same as image border pixel colors, use

```
#find out average pixel intensity 
border_val = tuple(np.mean(np.array(image)[0, :], axis=0))

# perform the actual rotation 
image = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (cols, rows),
                       borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                       borderValue=[int(i) for i in border_val])
```